# Prove that T is not a subspace in $M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb F)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

I need some help with this particular question,

$$T = \begin{Bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\\ c & d \end{bmatrix}, a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}\end{Bmatrix}$$

Prove that T is not a subspace of $M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb F)$.

I know that $T$ is non-empty, but how do I show that $T$ is not closed under addition or scalar multiplication?

Comment: Is $\frac{1}{2} \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr}$ in $T$?

Comment: I fear that this questions does not make sense in the first place. From what ring do the entries of a matrix in $M_{2 \times 2}$ come?

Comment: @Dylan_Carlo_Beck Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question. I made a mistake typing it in.

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you mean the vector space of $2 \times 2$ real matrices?

Comment: @Dylan_Carlo_Beck Yes, that is correct. I have fixed it again.

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ isn't a field.

Comment: Well, this notation suggests that you are dealing with a field (though, it might not be $\mathbb R$). But you can deduce from this that $M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb F)$ is not closed under scalar multiplication.